# Adding new field in model class using Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

In table i have column 'description' , which contain description of goods. 
I want include in CGridView column 'short_description', which will contain first 150 characters.

```
class Product extends CActiveRecord
{   
    /**
     * The followings are the available columns in table 'Product':
     * @var integer $id
     * @var integer $id_cat
     * @var string $title
     * @var string $description
     * @var timestamp $date
     */
    public $id;
    public $id_cat;
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $date;
    public $short_description ;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->short_description = substr($this->description, 0, 150);     
    }
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work .

Comment: Assuming you actually have columns in the table for id, id_cat, title, description and date, you do not need to declare them in your model. You DO need to declare the short_description variable however.

Answer (score 6):

You need to override afterFind function of model class and write the code

$this->short_description = substr($this->description, 0, 150);

in afterFind function.

You need to do some thing like this

```
protected function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->short_description = substr($this->description, 0, 150);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is right, you won't have access to `description` in the init(), but after the model is populated from the database you will have access to it in the afterFind() callback.

Comment: Thanks! I got exception 'property ... not defined' until I added  public $short_description; into model (as seen in question). That wasn't needed for other attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to define the function

```
public function getShortDescription()
{
   return substr($this->description, 0, 150);
}
```

Then you can call $product->shortDescription (using get magic method).

In this way the short description will only be "calculated" if needed, and not after every find even if it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Virtual Attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods). This is specifically designed to access altered variables. You can [read more here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods)

Inside the model you can make this function:

```
public function getShortDescription(){
        return substr($this->description, 0, 150);
}
```

You can also just add the variable at the top of the class:

```
public $shortDescription = substr($this->description, 0, 150);
```